# eclipse indigo major bug

Tags: eclipse, macos, eclipse-indigo

I have been using Eclipse forever, but only today I upgraded to Indigo.

- Using Eclipse Indigo on Mac 10.6 *

Files won't update after editing them and saving them. If I add blank lines and then save, then if I start debugging, the debugger will go through the lines that were there before, but now those lines are empty and the actual lines that the debugger is executing are a couple of lines below (due to the added blank lines). Debugger executes blank lines??!! Same thing if I change the code. If the file says X=5, and I change X=6, then debug, X will still be 5 ????!!!! Am I missing some editor caching option or smth ????

Things I have tried:
1. clean all projects, rebuild all projects
2. Delete projects, re-add them
3. delete files, write them from scratch
4. all auto-build and auto-refresh options are on
5. tried to change the workspace, the bug presists
6. tried to play around with the -xms128M and -Xmx786M option in the .ini file
7. tried restarting Eclipse and restarting computer

Comment: This might be surprising, but you haven't given as many details as you might think.  Which Indigo download (as in the actual file name)?  Which language are you working with?  Have you reported this bug to http://bugs.eclipse.org/ ?

Comment: @Martin, are you sure you don't get this problem if you switch back to the old version of eclipse?

Comment: Eclipse Version: 3.7.2.v20120207-1839
Build id: M20120208-0800

Downloaded from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

Filename: eclipse-jee-indigo-SR2-macosx-cocoa-x86_64.tar.gz

I haven't reported this bug, since I would think I am not the only one with it.

I haven't tried switching back to the old version, cause the old version is on my Window box. I have fresh-installed Indigo on my new MacBook Pro machine

Answer (score 0):

The problem was some discrepancy between the java version of the VM and the project's "facet" version. (whatever that is).

The thing I dont get is why the project was still running if there were problems reported on the "Problems" view and no new .class file was even compiled.  Why it was running an outdated .java  file, when the code on the actual display was different? (thus the ghost effect).

Is there an option that allows the eclipse to run outdated .class files if no new .class file could be compiled cause of compile errors?